# adding entries to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm having trouble with adding dictionary's to a nsmutabledictionary. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
@interface viewMap : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {

     NSMutableDictionary *onclickDic;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *onclickDic;
@end

@implementation viewMap
@synthesize onclickDic;

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    NSString *pushLat   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [annotation coordinate].latitude];
    NSString *pushLng   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [annotation coordinate].longitude];

    NSDictionary *latlngDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pushLat, pushLng, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"lat", @"lng", nil]];

    NSDictionary *toPush    = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:latlngDic forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];


    NSLog(@"toPush is %@", toPush); // this one is correct and works

    [self.onclickDic addEntriesFromDictionary:toPush];

    NSLog(@"onclickDic is %@", onclickDic); // this one gives (null)
}
@end
```

Comment: "Having trouble with" without some more information is a problem. What exactly goes wrong? If there is an error message, what is it, and where does the error happen?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis Thanks for your answer. The answers below helped me out. I forgot to alloc/init and release the object clickDic

Comment: Still, next time you have a question, please provide more info. People were apparently able to guess your problem, but it can't be found in what you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't ever create the `onclickDic`.  You also never release it.

Try adding these methods:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    if (self)
    {
        onclickDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [onclickDict release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like `onclickDic` is ever assigned.  Make sure you are allocating an instance before your `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method gets called.

Also, not related to the problem, but your `toPush` dictionary is unnecessary.  Just add the key/value to `onclickDic` directly:

```
[onclickDic setValue:latlngDic forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to instantiate `self.onclickDic` anywhere. Even with `@synthesize`, this is not done for you. Best place for that is probably `init`.

The reason the call is not failing, is that it's OK in Objective C to call a function on a `nil` object. This is commonly used when calling methods of delegates, for example.

Comment: Thanks, it works now with: onclickDic  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; What is the best way/moment to release the object? because it can't be done in the method where Im adding the object i guess.